# How to overload operators with a method name in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Let's say I have a class named Foo:

```
Class Foo
  def method=(params)
    puts params
  end
  def +(params)
    puts params
  end
  def method+(params)
    puts params
  end
end
```

In the above, after initializing the class to a new object, which I'll call myobj (myobj = Foo.new), calling myobj.method = "string" and myobj + "string" will both print that string.  However, a syntax error is thrown when I try to define method+.  I want to be able to call myobj.method + "string".  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

This is not actually a case of what characters can appear in method names ('+' is technically allowed), but rather the parsing and precedence rules of the language.

The reason `def method=` works is that it is Ruby's special syntax for property accessors. When you define `method=`, semantically you are saying that the foo has an accessible `@method` instance variable, or at least acts like it.

It is a special case, and all other operators bind less strongly than the `.` method call. In `foo.method + "string"`, `method` is called on `foo` and then `+("string")` is called on the result.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby won't let you define a `whatever+` method like it will with `whatever=` - if you need the behaviour you're describing, you'll need to make a "method" object, define the `+` operator for it, and return it from a call to `Foo.method`:

```
class Method
    def + (params)
        puts params
    end

    def = (params)
        puts params
    end
end

class Foo
    def + (params)
        puts params
    end

    def method
        return Method.new
    end
end
```

I've moved the `=` operator into the method object as well, but that one doesn't really matter (since you can `def method=`) - it just seemed logical.  And if you need to put this into practice, you should probably make Method a member class of Foo:

```
class Foo
    class Method
    end
end
```

so you keep your namespaces clean.  You can always use `Foo::Method` to get at that class when you need it.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

A method is not an object, and operators are attributes of objects, not methods.  This won't work.